# Connect to multiple ftp servers using Spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have been spring integration, I want to connect multiple ftp server to retrieve files from  remote locations, could anyone give me good example how to connect multiple ftp servers using spring integration

Thank you in advance,
Udeshika

Answer (score 2):

The [Dynamic FTP Sample](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) explores a technique for creating multiple parameterized contexts on the outbound side. On the inbound side you have to make the context a child of the main context, so that it has access to the channel to which to send the files. This is discussed in [this Spring Forum Thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?128303-Dynamic-Inbound-Channel-Adapter-creation) and other threads linked from there.